# Bootstrap Variance in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Trying to do a bootstrap variance of an estimator in R and having a difficult time. Essentially, I'm trying to pull out 50 random rows out of a larger dataset, then, from those 50 rows, bootstrap 1000 times a specific estimator (formula below) using a sample size of 20, and then, from there, calculate the variance between the estimators. My code is below. I am very lost.

```
vector = d()
bootstraprows <- data[sample(nrow(data), 50), ]
for (i:100){
i <- sample(nrow(bootstraprows), size=20, replace=T)
c <- (sum(i$mpg*i$weight))/(sum((i$weight)^2))
append(d, c)
}
var(d)
```

As noted, I'm trying to calculator the sum of MPG * weight divided by the sum of weight^2. Please help if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you seek to accomplish, but I tried to construct an example. I used the built-in `mtcars` dataset that comes with R.

```
# load sample data
data(mtcars) 
df <- mtcars
# show data structure
str(df) 
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
$ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
$ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
$ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
$ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
$ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
$ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
$ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
$ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
$ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
$ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
# fix randomization seed, make sample() reproducible
set.seed(1)
# take random 10 rows from df
sampleSize <- 10
bRows <- df[sample(nrow(df), sampleSize), ]
# do 7 bootstrap replications
bSamples <- 7
# make container for results
bResults <- rep(NA, bSamples)
```

Now we can actually perform the bootstrap

```
# loop over bootstraps
for (b in seq_len(bSamples)) { 
  # make bootstrap draw from bRows
  bData <- bRows[sample(sampleSize, size = sampleSize, replace = TRUE), ]
  # compute your statistic of interest
  bValue <- sum(bData[["mpg"]] * bData[["wt"]]) / sum((bData[["wt"]])^2)
  # store results in container
  bResults[[b]] <- bValue
}
# show what we computed
bResults
[1] 4.490459 6.297782 3.651372 3.612414 5.348291 5.149250 3.818677
```

Does any of this help?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much! :)